# Generating code snippets in Visual Studio MacOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

When you begin typing a command, for example 'for', the snippet appears in the auto-complete drop down but I can't figure out how to generate the snippet.

I've tried <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and double clicking but neither seem to do the trick. Could there be an option in preferences I'm missing?

Comment: Press Tab twice.

Comment: Gah! Thank you! I knew it would be something obvious